# Is $f$ Riemann integrable if $\epsilon>1$ and if $\epsilon<1$?

Tags: integration, analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function.

(1) If for each $\epsilon>1$ there is a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$ then does it follow that $f$ is integrable?

(2) If for each $\epsilon<1$ there is a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$ then does it follow that $f$ is integrable?

$$$$

From (1) it doesn't follow that $f$ isintegrable, because since $\epsilon$ is not small enough it doesn't necessarily follow that $\underline\int_a^bf=\overline\int_a^bf$ and so Riemann criterion is not satisfied and $f$ is not integrable.

Is that correct?

At (2) it follows that $f$ is integrable, or not?

Comment: $f$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$ iff $f$ is bounded and the subset of discontinuity points has measure zero

Comment: That means that (1) is excluded from this argument, right? @AlvinLepik

Comment: The question is not whether (1) is "excluded from this argument". The question is whether the implication in (1) is false. To prove that implication is false, you must find a counterexample, i.e. you must find a non-integral function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$, a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, and a number $\epsilon > 1$, such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \epsilon$. That is exactly what is done in the answer by @AlvinLepik.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :-) @LeeMosher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the Dirichlet function on $[0,1]$: $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1, &x\in\mathbb Q \\ 0, &x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\end{cases}.$$ The difference $U(f,P)-L(f,P) \leqslant 1$, but it is not a Riemann integrable function. (The inequality holds for any partition $P$ in this example).

The function $f = I_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q}$ is Lebesgue integrable, since $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ is measurable (its measure is zero).

---

(2) is true, because if $\varepsilon >0$ is arbitrary, we can by assumption for every $\varepsilon ' < 1$ find $P$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \varepsilon ' \leqslant \varepsilon$. Equivalently, $f$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Is this for the case (2) ? I got stuck right now.

Comment: Case (2) holds, because we don't really care about large $\varepsilon$, it's just a formality.

Comment: In (1) which partition do we consider?

Comment: @MaryStar Any partition you want. Given a partition, what is the highest possible value for $U$ and lowest possible value for $L$?

Comment: Could you give me an example for $P$ ? Couldwe take for example for $P$ the whole $[0,1]$ ? The highest possible value for $U$ is $1$ and the lowest possible value for $L$ is $0$, right?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, we can take the trivial partition. Yes, those bounds are correct and therefore, no matter your choice of partition, the difference must always be some number between $0$ and $1$, which is sufficient to complete the argument.

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you very mich for your help!! :-)